# Create specified correlation between variables (by permutation) in R

Tags: r, statistics, permutation

I am looking for a way to create a specified correlation between 2 variables, regardless of their distribution, given that the ordening is allowed to change. The motivation has to do with Bayesian statistics.

Imagine variable `a` which holds 100 random normal numbers, while
variable `b` holds the numbers 1...100.

There will be `100 factorial` permutations possible, and most of the time correlations between -0.95 and 0.95 will exist among all possible permutations of variable `b`.

I wrote a little script in R to try to find the correlation in an iterative way.

- Iterate through all the indexes, checking whether the previous correlation is 
  lower or higher than the sought correlation.
- If the correlation is too low it will switch the number belonging to the index with the number belonging to a random index lower.
- If the correlation is too high it will switch the number belonging to the index with the number belonging to a random index higher.
- It will then check whether the new correlation is better than the old one, and keep the one closest to the wanted correlation.
- It will keep going over all the indices in order (from 1 to 100), and after every iteration it then checks whether it is within the wanted correlation +/- tolerance and return the permuted variable.

Usually in around 2000 iterations the specified correlation will be found by a tolerance of 0.0005.

[image: Note that index here is actually iteration]

Index in the picture represents iterations.

My question is how to do this permutation in a smarter way, such that the correlation will be quicker found.

Comment: I'd like to add that general information on how to approach this might already be useful... how to get a better understanding of how to improve finding correlation.

Comment: Would it be possible somehow to use root finding?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing. I would shoot for something like it, where at each iteration a lot of random permutations are considered and the best (closest in absolute value to your objective) is kept. Overall, something a little more random and maybe more vectorized than your high level description suggests.

Comment: I am running the benchmark on it now. I realized my code had some small flaws. Your method will be more efficient I think when I try to extend this to more variables. Thank you. Maybe try to extend this comment so that it will make a nice answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel)'s idea to, at each iteration, propose several candidates. Here it actually tests all candidates; while this is fine for my variables of length 100, a sample should be preferred later for more cases.

```
AnnealCor <- function(x, y, corpop, tol) {  
    while(abs(cor(x,y) - corpop) > tol) {       
        for (i in 1:length(y)) {
            numbers <- 1:length(y)
            correlation <- 1:length(y)
            for (j in numbers) {
                switcher <- y
                switcher[c(i,j)] <- y[c(j,i)]
                correlation[j] <- cor(x, switcher) 
            }
        tokeep <- which(abs(correlation - corpop) ==  min(abs(correlation - corpop)))[1]
        y[c(i, tokeep)] <- y[c(tokeep,i)]
        if (abs(cor(x,y) - corpop) < tol) {break}
        }
    }
    return(y)
}
```

Benchmark time based on 100 repetitions has a median of 200 miliseconds.